# How to insert wp_users ->user login name to wp_terms when a new user registering?

Tags: php, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, wpdb

i need to insert wp_users -> user_login field to wp_terms name and slugs field,when a new user registering.

my requirement is admin needs to assign posts to specific users, that is admin need to add a post to user1 ,but user2 should not see that.for this i created a custom post and add taxonomy for that.And the terms are users Usernames .so i need to list the usernames of the users as terms in the taxonomy.when a new user is registered his username should updated in the wp_terms table also,so i will get the usernames as terms.

i stucked here .please suggest some solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution for this

```
add_action('user_register', function ($user_id) {
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user_name = $user_info->user_login;
    wp_insert_term($user_name, 'user1', array());
}, 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to to add username as the term of specific taxonomie.
You need to use "**user_register**" hook.
So the sample code is bellow

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_term_to_taxonomie', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) ){
        wp_insert_term(
          $_POST['user_login'], // the term 
          'product', // the taxonomy
        );
    }

}
```

Try the code , and replace "product" with your taxonomie name.
Then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: hi   i replaced the product with my taxonomy user1 and copied the code in function.php but it not working the code i replaced is    add_action( 'user_register', 'add_term_to_taxonomie', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) ){
        wp_insert_term(
          $_POST['user_login'], // the term 
          'user1', // the taxonomy
        );
    }

}